# Is multiplicative inverse defined for ideal? Eg. $x^3 y\in \langle x^3 y^2\rangle$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, terminology, ideals

> **Definition.** A subset $I\subset k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ is an ideal if
>
> i. $0\in I.$
>
> ii. If $f,g\in I$, then $f+g\in I$.
>
> iii. If $f\in I$ and $h\in k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$, then $hf\in I$.

I think the point $i$ above implies directly that the multiplicative inverse is not defined in ideal. I want to make sure I understand this totally so is multiplicative inverse defined for ideal? No because $0\in I$? And $x^3 y\not\in \langle x^3y^3\rangle$?

Comment: There aren't nontrivial multiplicative inverses in the ring you started with, so there definetly aren't a subset of the ring

Comment: What do you mean "the multiplicative inverse" for an ideal? Do you mean an ideal $J$ such that $IJ = 1$? Or do you mean that for every nonzero element in the ideal, there exists a unit in the ideal?